# javascript find object by same keys and merge them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

So i'm have an array of objects, i've created two dictonaries to map the names.
I want to find all object with the same key and merge them. Also concatenate that values.
Here is what i've done, but stucked:

```
const wordcloudData = {
  'pretty cool': [3, 1, ['161', '329']],
  'pretty damn': [2, 1, ['111', '131']],
  'pretty nice': [1, 1, ['211', '499']],
  'great': [4, 1, ['18', '19']],
};

const dict = {
  'pretty cool': 1, 
  'pretty damn': 1,
  'pretty nice': 1,
};

const dictNames = {
  1: 'nice',
}


const formattedArray = _
  .chain(wordcloudData)
  .keys()
  .map(item => {
    const [weight, color, reviews] = wordcloudData[item];

    return {
      name: dictNames[dict[item]] || item,
      weight: weight,
      color: color,
      reviews: reviews,
    }
  })
  /* Here i'm getting that type of array:
   [ 
    { name: 'nice', weight: 1, color: 1, reviews: [ '211', '499' ] },
    { name: 'nice', weight: 2, color: 1, reviews: [ '111', '131' ] },
    { name: 'nice', weight: 3, color: 1, reviews: [ '161', '329' ] },
    { name: 'great', weight: 4, color: 1, reviews: [ '18', '19' ] } 
   ]
  */
  .groupBy('name')
  .map(_.spread(_.assign)) // Here i'm trying to get rid of objects with same key, but something goes wrong
  .value();
```

I think i'm doing it wrong when removing duplicates?
What should i do next?

To explain what I want, will show what array I want it to be:

**Initial array of object:**

```
{
 'pretty cool': [3, 1, ['161', '329']],
 'pretty damn': [2, 1, ['111', '131']],
 'pretty nice': [1, 1, ['211', '499']],
 'great': [4, 1, ['18', '19']],
};
```

**Result array of objects:**

```
{ name: 'nice', weight: 6, color: 1, reviews: [ '161', '329', '111', '131', '211', '499'] },
{ name: 'great', weight: 4, color: 1, reviews: [ '18', '19' ] }
```

Comment: Add an example of the end result of the that the wordcloudData in the example should create?

Comment: @OriDrori thanks, I've added

Comment: Would you accept an answer not using lodash? Also what the final value of the color would be if all the items have different values when you are merging they?

Comment: yes, i will accept answer with not using lodash, color values will be the same for mapping items, one of the reason, i'm not pointed in final result to be color an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.mergeWith()` and choose how to combine the values according to the key:

```js
const wordcloudData = {
  'pretty cool': [3, 1, ['161', '329']],
  'pretty damn': [2, 1, ['111', '131']],
  'pretty nice': [1, 1, ['211', '499']],
  'great': [4, 1, ['18', '19']],
};

const dict = {
  'pretty cool': 1, 
  'pretty damn': 1,
  'pretty nice': 1,
};

const dictNames = {
  1: 'nice',
}

const merger = _.partial(_.invoke, {
  weight: _.add,
  reviews: _.concat,
});

const formattedArray = _(wordcloudData)
  .map(([weight, color, reviews], item) => ({
    name: _.get(dictNames, dict[item], item),
    weight,
    color,
    reviews
  }))
  .groupBy('name')
  .map(v => _.mergeWith(...v, (o, s, k) => merger(k, o, s)))
  .value();
  
console.log(formattedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will stick with your choice

Answer (score 1):

Here you have one version without `lodash` and using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const wordcloudData = {
  'pretty cool': [3, 1, ['161', '329']],
  'pretty damn': [2, 1, ['111', '131']],
  'pretty nice': [1, 1, ['211', '499']],
  'great': [4, 1, ['18', '19']],
};

const dict = {
  'pretty cool': 1, 
  'pretty damn': 1,
  'pretty nice': 1,
};

const dictNames = {
  1: 'nice',
}

let merged = Object.keys(wordcloudData).reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    let new_name = dictNames[dict[curr]] || curr;
    let [weigth, color, review] = wordcloudData[curr];
    let found = res.findIndex(x => x.name === new_name);
    
    if (found >= 0)
    {        
        res[found].weigth += weigth;
        res[found].color = color;
        res[found].review.push(...review);
    }
    else
    {
        res.push({
            name: new_name,
            weigth: weigth,
            color: color,
            review: review
        });
    }

    return res;

}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short solution using plain ES6, and separating the merge logic into its own function: https://jsbin.com/qevohugene/edit?js,console

```
const wordcloudData = {
  'pretty cool': [3, 1, ['161', '329']],
  'pretty damn': [2, 1, ['111', '131']],
  'pretty nice': [1, 1, ['211', '499']],
  'great': [4, 1, ['18', '19']],
};

const dict = {
  'pretty cool': 1, 
  'pretty damn': 1,
  'pretty nice': 1,
};

const dictNames = {
  1: 'nice',
}

const mergeItems = (oldItem, newItem) => ({
  name: newItem.name,
  weight: newItem.weight + oldItem.weight,
  color: newItem.color,
  reviews: [...oldItem.reviews, ...newItem.reviews]
});

const formattedArray = Object.entries(wordcloudData)
  .map(([key, [weight, color, reviews]]) => ({
      name: dictNames[dict[key]] || key,
      weight: weight,
      color: color,
      reviews: reviews,
    }))
  .reduce((accum, item) => {
    return accum.some(x => x.name === item.name)
      ? accum.map(x => x.name === item.name ? mergeItems(x, item) : x)
      : [...accum, item];
  }, []);
console.log(formattedArray)
```

Hope that helps.